# My party is not following me in Divinity Original Sin 2

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

When my character moves the rest of the party doesn't follow

Comment: You can answer your own answer, but you might consider improving it. You should write your question and your answer as if they were a real answer to a real question, with research effort and real explanations from both sides. You might want to read this section about [How do I ask a good question?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and this meta about [Showing research effort for self answered Q&A](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12275/228547). You might want to add more context specially to your question, as what you already tried to solve the original behavior.

Answer (score 2):

On the top left of the screen you have to drag and drop the characters portraits so that they chain together. They will follow if they are chained.

Another reason for not following is if there are damaging barriers between the party and the leader, like fire.